# Why does my site works properly in IE7 mode in IE9 but not IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, mode

I have a problem with IE9. I am using this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

So as to have IE7 mode in all browsers. IE8 and IE9 work fine; they work like IE7. Native IE7 does not work properly. Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly isn't working correctly? The X-UA-Compatible tag was introduced in IE8. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx

Comment: The css in the page works as it should and the site looks as it should. While in IE7 the css is a mess. I though that this X-UA-Compatible would make all the browsers behave like IE7, but IE7 itself has problem.

Comment: Why are you limiting the capabilities of newer versions of IE by what IE7 could do? IE9 should be able to handle most if not all of the same things as Chrome, Firefox and Opera

Answer (score 0):

i think it may be this
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
i got that from here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx